# Kafka Streams: Exception not caught by try-catch block

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am using Spring with kafka Streams. I am trying to simulate an error scenario. As you can see from the code, if I pass the input value as 0 to one of the input topics, I will get an `divide by 0` exception.

I have wrapped the error causing section in a try-catch block assuming that the error will be caught by the catch block.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Topology {

    private static final Serde<String> STRING_SERDE = Serdes.String();

    @Autowired
    void KStreamsTopology(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
        KStream<String, String> messageStream = streamsBuilder
                .stream(List.of("quickstart-events", "sample-input"), Consumed.with(STRING_SERDE, STRING_SERDE).withName("my-inputs"));
        try {
            messageStream
                    .peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("Input Key: " + k + ", value: " + v))
                    .mapValues(a -> getAnInt(Integer.parseInt(a)))
                    .foreach((k, v) -> System.out.println("output Key: " + k + ", Output value: " + v));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
           log.error("Exceptions occurred in my Topology:: " + exception.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private int getAnInt(Integer value) {
        return 10 / value;
    }
}
```

But the error is not caught. Instead, the below exception is thrown and the application stops.

```
2022-08-10 23:26:27.218  INFO 40343 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [kafka-streams-poc-de132014-fb30-4c10-b5d5-7b190c3e38db-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
Exception in thread "kafka-streams-poc-de132014-fb30-4c10-b5d5-7b190c3e38db-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=my-inputs, topic=sample-input, partition=0, offset=10, stacktrace=java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.techopact.kafkastreamspoc.topology.Topology.getAnInt(Topology.java:37)
    at com.techopact.kafkastreamspoc.topology.Topology.lambda$KStreamsTopology$1(Topology.java:28)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.AbstractStream.lambda$withKey$2(AbstractStream.java:111)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPeek$KStreamPeekProcessor.process(KStreamPeek.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:809)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1296)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:784)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:604)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:576)

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:758)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1296)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:784)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:604)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:576)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.techopact.kafkastreamspoc.topology.Topology.getAnInt(Topology.java:37)
    at com.techopact.kafkastreamspoc.topology.Topology.lambda$KStreamsTopology$1(Topology.java:28)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.AbstractStream.lambda$withKey$2(AbstractStream.java:111)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPeek$KStreamPeekProcessor.process(KStreamPeek.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:809)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:731)
    ... 4 more
2022-08-10 23:31:26.921  INFO 40343 --- [90c3e38db-admin] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=kafka-streams-poc-de132014-fb30-4c10-b5d5-7b190c3e38db-admin] Node -1 disconnected.
2022-08-10 23:36:27.007  INFO 40343 --- [90c3e38db-admin] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=kafka-streams-poc-de132014-fb30-4c10-b5d5-7b190c3e38db-admin] Node 0 disconnected.
```

I am aware that this is not the right way to handle exceptions in Kafka Stream application. I see a nice detailed article [here](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/hands-on-error-handling/). But I am still curious as to why the exception is not caught by the catch block.

Comment: It is not called because you try to catch an error on the configuration phase. Those Kafka Streams operations are really called at runtime on different threads. You have to `try..catch` inside those your functions. See also `StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler` which you can provide for the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` via a `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, I tried your suggestion. I have updated the question with the new set of configuration as you suggested. But still the Error thread won't be replaced by a new one. Can you please help?

Comment: Well, by I suggested a `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer`, not `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer`

Comment: Oh ok, Is there an example or reference that you can share?

Comment: There is the one in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafka-streams-example

Comment: That did work either because I was trying use your suggestion in my Spring cloud stream app which does not make sense. So I posted a separate question to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some print statements to the code.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Topology {

    private static final Serde<String> STRING_SERDE = Serdes.String();

    @Autowired
    void KStreamsTopology(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
        KStream<String, String> messageStream = streamsBuilder
                .stream(List.of("sample-input"),
                        Consumed.with(STRING_SERDE, STRING_SERDE).withName("my-inputs"));
        try {
            System.out.println("Start.... " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            messageStream
                    .peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("Input Key: " + k + ", value: " + v))
                    .mapValues(a -> getAnInt(Integer.parseInt(a)))
                    .foreach((k, v) -> System.out.println("output Key: " + k + ", Output value: " + v));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
           log.error("Exceptions occurred in my Topology:: " + exception.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private int getAnInt(Integer value) {
        System.out.println("Inside getInt:: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return 10 / value;
    }
}
```

I saw these lines in the output.

```
Start.... main 
Inside getInt:: kafka-streams-poc-45acf83e-411f-4a21-833e-c7d9ccf1fe90-StreamThread-1
```

As Artem Bilan pointed out, the Kafka stream nodes are run in a different thread other than the `main` thread